# how to deserialize json string using newtonsoft

Tags: json, xamarin.android

hello i send request to server and i want to deserialize json string using newtonsoft

here is my code

```
  public static async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
    {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://52.163.215.46:4444/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                //POST Method
                VMLogin data = new VMLogin() { Id = 1, NAME = "abhijit22", PROF_EMAILD = "abhijit@gmail.com", MAILID = "abhijit@gmail.com" };

                    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var responsePost = client.PostAsync("api/FBLogins", content);
                    if (responsePost.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Get the URI of the created resource.
                        Uri returnUrl = responsePost.Result.Headers.Location;
                        Console.WriteLine(returnUrl);

                //how to deserialize json string
            }
        }
    }
public class VMLogin
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string PROF_EMAILD { get; set; }
        public string MAILID { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginResponse
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
```

How to deserialize json string which i got as a responce from server......

Answer (score 0):

This is the line for deserializing JSON into the class model (I assume the model for the response is LoginResponse)

```
LoginResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(json_str);
```

Where **json_str** is the json string reponse you got from the server